# Convert qtvr file to mov

Tags: mp4, movie, panoramas, mov

I have received QTVR files (Panorama files) from my client and I was supposed to convert it to mov, and later convert it to mp4.

Does anybody know any softwares to convert them? I have used Pano2Movie, but it seems my trial version is already outdated, so I can't use it again.

Comment: If you convert it to mp4, you will loose all panorama functionality

Answer (score 0):

You should try [QTVR2MOV](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Other-VIDEO-Tools/QTVR2MOV.shtml)

(Sorry, missed the part, where you mentioned you had Pano2Movie already)

Comment: Wow. Site it was on was changed. Try torrents.